# Is it safe to have a std::array of dynamic object?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, stl, c++11

Is it safe to have a `std::array` of dynamic object, for example `std::array<std::string, 3>`, and to resize the contents (the strings) ? (because it can be problematic to have a raw C array of strings)

Comment: How do you resize a `std::array`?

Comment: All you're doing when you resize the string is changing memory pointed to by a pointer contained in your array.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `std::string arr[3];`?

Comment: @ildjarn you can add some nice features like bounds checking, copying/assignment etc. The built in arrays are rather limited in their functionality.

Comment: @DougT. : I understand the advantage of `std::array<>` over C-arrays, but the OP said "*it can be problematic to have a raw C array of strings*", which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because `std::array` is a just a friendly template that wraps an underlying C style aray array. You can think of it as something like this:

```
template <typename T, int size>
class Array {
...
   T vals[size];
}
```

Change T to string above and you'll quickly realize that anything that you can do to the contents of an array of strings you can do with a `std::array` of strings. This includes resizing, deleting, whatever you can imagine.

To think even deeper about it, think about it this way. The `std::array` holds a string. The string has no idea where its being held. The array might tell the string to make a copy of itself (through a copy constructor or assignment), when say the array itself is assigned. However, this is its entirely through the string's public interface. The fact that the string is being held by any data structure doesn't limit that string's functionality, it just makes the holder (in this case `std::array`) yet another client of the `string`'s public interface.

As containers like `std::array` need to work with a large variety of types, they tend to make relatively few typically well documented assumptions on the type `T` passed in. Stuff like requiring that T can be copy constructed, default constructed, and assigned. Then its typically up to the implementer* of `T` to ensure these few assumptions are valid.

<sub>*There is a very advanced topic called template specialization where one could write a specialized version of array just for say "string". Aside from `vector<bool>` these are pretty rare with the standard containers.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean resizing the strings, then yes.